# Renaming a PDF streamed by Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, download

Using the right mix of XSLT, XSL-FO and Apache FOP, I am able to send a PDF into some browser window.
In fact, I am sending the file content as follows:

```
           response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength( out.size());
            response.getOutputStream().write( out.toByteArray());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

As expected, the browser shows the PDF content in a tab named "pdf", and if I save the file locally, the name also defaults to pdf.pdf
**How can I force the file name?**

I tried the following among other things that didn't work:

```
           response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=" + filename + ".pdf" );
```

For clarity I want to display the content in the browser (as opposed to a straight download)

Comment: Change `inline` to `attachment`. That *should* do it.

Comment: It does set the file name but also forces the save-as popup which I don't want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=48651)

Basically, it's a matter of changing the URL pattern in web.xml
The browser will use whatever the page name looks like
I used to have

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PDF</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

which I replaced with

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PDF</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Invoking the servlet using `http://wherever/pdf/filename.pdf?param1=va1...` changes the file name to "filename.pdf"