# Servlet download File from remote Server

Tags: java, spring, servlets, model-view-controller, download

I need to create a Servlet which offers files from an external Server and sends it to the user.

```
www.downloadServiceUrl.com/download/path-to-external-stored-file
```

as I don't want the servlet to be a "man in the middle", I need it to serve the file without pretransferring it to itself and then resubmitting it to the user for performance-issues (otherwise each download takes at least 2 times as long as it needs - not speaking about speed bottlenecks between these servers.

Is this possible anyhow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I think this could be done is if your java process can access the file system where your files reside. Your webapp can only serve files in its context, not outside, thus you need to access the file system of the external server.

Comment: can't this just be done by sending a download-header back to the user so that he can access the file from the browser (e.g. just renamed)?

Comment: What do you mean by download-header?

Comment: something like "setHeader("location:<the path to the file>, Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="+realFilename+); i just need to rename  the file while downloading, as it is accesisble without problems in the web...

Comment: I think this question might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448846/renaming-a-pdf-streamed-by-java-servlet

Comment: thanks for the link, but this does not solve the problem of the "servlet in the middle" i think?

Comment: That's right. I misunderstood when you said you just need the file renamed when the user downloads it. If you are accessing the servlet (i.e. the webapp) to obtain a file that resides in another server, the servlet would always be the thing in the middle (or can I say middleware?), wouldn't it? Also, you can check the list of response headers available and I'm not sure there's something there you can use for your case. My best bet for your solution is as my answer above.